# How do you get a dev token on Product Hunt?

Tags: ruby, api, token, access-token

I'm trying to pull some information with a little Ruby code on Product Hunt and I need a dev token. How can I get access to one? The api docs are super confusing....

https://api.producthunt.com/v1/docs

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign in to Product Hunt. Then on the docs page you linked to, there is a section that reads:

> But… i just wanted to run a simple script?
>
> The oauth2 flow is a bit of a overkill if you just want to run a few
>   scripts We provide a developer_token (does not expire, linked to your
>   account) in the [app dashboard](https://www.producthunt.com/v1/oauth/applications)

Click that link, create your app, and you should be able to create your token.